There is a unique coupling between a probability distribution $\mu$ and a degenerate distribution $\mu_0$.
By degenerate distribution I intend https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degenerate_distribution.
I cannot see why the set of couplings between some probability measure and a constant would be a singleton. Also, can anybody provide an intuition of what the p-Wasserstein distance between $\mu$ and $\mu_0$ would be?
Thanks in advance

Please clarify what you mean by a "degenerate distribution". This wikipedia page is quite vague. Do you just mean a Dirac measure? Then, the answer is given by the linked question of Mittens.

The linked question answers mine! Thanks a lot
